# Blocking connections from/to Palau?

Tags: python, cmd, packet

Is there any way to block all coming/sending packets to Palau (it's country :P)? Palau's domain is .pw .

I'd like to block it in one of these ways:

- Command prompt command
- Python

OS: Windows 7 64bit
Python v.: 2.7

Answer (score 2):

I found this as part of an .htaccess file:

```
order allow,deny
#
# Block from PALAU (PW)
#
deny from 103.30.248.0/22
deny from 103.251.132.0/23
deny from 202.124.224.0/20
allow from all
```

Apparently these are Palau's assigned IPv4 blocks.

Comment: Were did you get the ranges from?

Comment: @Kay: http://incredibill.me/htaccess-block-country-ips